# zend form with arrays having same index

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I need to obtain something like this in zend

```
<input type="text" name="phone[1]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="address[1]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="banana[1]" value="whatever" />
```

Notice they have the same id inside the brackets! (i don't need `name="phone[]"` , or `name="phone[phone1]"`)

I've tried and 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3673034/579646 and 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/406268/579646 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/7061713/579646

The problem is in ZendFramework i end up having to name 3 elements with the same name "1" and the last overwrites the previous. Even if i create 3 subforms i get the same effect.

Different examples show how to obtain an array with different indexes or no index(`[]`), but i need different array to have the same index.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zend_Form has a feature for this named `setElementsBelongTo`. See
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.advanced.html

The way of use this is setting to the Zend_Form object the prefix with `setElementsBelongTo`, if you want iterate over each field then you can use subforms to encapsulate each group of fields

You can call to `setElementsBelongTo` in your controller or in the `init()` method of your form class:

```
$mainForm = new Zend_Form();

$phoneForm = new Zend_Form_Subform();
$element = $phoneForm->createElement('text', '1'); // 1 is the element inside of the brackets
$phoneForm->addElement($element);
$phoneForm->setElementsBelongTo('phone'); // phone is the part leading the brackets
$mainForm->addSubform($phoneForm, 'phone_form');

$phoneForm = new Zend_Form_Subform();
$element = $phoneForm->createElement('text', '2'); // 1 is the element inside of the brackets
$phoneForm->addElement($element);
$phoneForm->setElementsBelongTo('phone'); // phone is the part leading the brackets
$mainForm->addSubform($phoneForm, 'phone_form2');

$addressForm = new Zend_Form_Subform();
$element = $addressForm->createElement('text', '1');
$addressForm->addElement($element);
$addressForm->setElementsBelongTo('address');
$mainForm->addSubform($addressForm, 'address_form');

echo $mainForm;

var_dump($mainForm->getValues());
```

gives

```
 array(2) { 
["phone"]=> array(2) { [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL } 
["address"]=> array(1) { [1]=> NULL } }
```

To get your expected result you will need remove some decorators (Form, dt, etc):

```
<input type="text" name="phone[1]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="address[2]" value="" />
```

Then when you retrieve the values with `$form->getValues()` the result is:

```
Array(
   'phone' = Array(
       '1' => <value>,
   ),
   'address' = Array(
       '1' => <value>,
   )
);
```

Comment: zend madness, i have to create a subform for each input?

Comment: Well max4ever, there are tools, it's your choice choose one or mix them for your own needs

Comment: it doesn't quite work as you pointed, i get <input name="1[phone]" /> instead of <input name="phone[1]" />

Answer (score 0):

i do not understand, why you need this special case, but the only possible solution in my opinion is, to use a custom template.

```
class YourForm extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->setDecorators(array(
            array(
                'ViewScript',
                array(
                    'viewScript' => 'path/to/your/phtml/file',
                    'possibleOtherParamYouWantToPass' => 'value',
                    ...
                )
            )
        ));
    }
}
```

So what you do is, you say that you want to use a template file, where you can declare everything by yourself. Also your `banana[1]`.

But you will lose simple validation and other benefits.

Comment: i need the validation and the other benefits, that's where the challenge is